# How to make a field in google datastore unique

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

is it possible to make name=db.StringProperty(unique=True)  ?...
any other way to make it unique.?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_or_insert` will ensure uniqueness of the record via it's key.

```
Model.get_or_insert (key_name, **kwds)
```

> Attempts to get the entity of the model's kind with the given key
>   name. If it exists, get_or_insert() simply returns it. If it doesn't
>   exist, a new entity with the given kind, name, and parameters in kwds
>   is created, stored, and returned.
>   The get and subsequent (possible) put operations are wrapped in a
>   transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that get_or_insert() will
>   never overwrite an existing entity, and will insert a new entity if
>   and only if no entity with the given kind and name exists.

[Get_Or_Insert](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert)